# JasperReport Server Visualize.js - Embedding the report designer

Tags: jasperserver, visualize

I am using visualize.js and JasperReports Server Pro version. Using visualize it pretty straight forward to embed the report which is already designed and stored in the repository.

But is there a way to embed the report designer component using the visualize.js?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if for Report designer you mean the ad hoc feature , this is not embeddable via visualize.js . You can embed it in your application using the HTTP api approach (using iframe) . You can do that adding in the url the parameter decorate=no

See more details  [here](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/embedding-using-http-api)

This approach it is pretty easy to implement and you can also apply a theme to JasperReports Server to change the colors and the css of the UI. So it will look exactly as part of your application

You find a video explanation of this feature 
[here](http://community.jaspersoft.com/blog/jaspersoft-tech-talks-episode-21-jaspersoft-themes-0)

If for report designer you mean jaspersoft Studio, the answer is still: it is not possible

Remember you can aleay contact Jaspersoft Support for issues related to commercial version of Jaspersoft

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, I have already implemented Http API approach, just that the IFrame makes things challenging to handle session and designer events from the parent application.